# Multi-level meta: do I include a measure of precision in subgroup analysis model?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

In a meta-regression model, a precision measure (SE or SE^2) is often included in the model along with covariates. Is the same true for subgroup analysis in a multi-level analysis wherein moderators are tested individually? For example:

moderertorX <- rma.mv(MarginalEffect, Variance, mods = ~ SE + moderertorX, random = list(~ 1 | EffectSize_ID, ~1 | Study_ID), tdist=TRUE, data=EmployBinaryITT)